# Can Arduino Uno run more than two software uart commnications?

Tags: arduino, uart

I am working on an application where I am required to communicate with 6 Arduino Unos  from one master Arduino Uno. the six Arduino boards are placed at the 1-meter distance from the main Arduino Uno. Therefore I cannot use SPI or I2C am I correct? is this possible to do with software UARTs in Arduino Uno? 6 UARTs communication with software serial? if this is not possible how to do this?

Comment: The max length of your cables for SPI and I2C depend on what baud rate you will use

Comment: There are I2C Extenders that allow for bigger distances.
With other Hardware support you can also turn Serial into a bus system with one Master and multiple Slaves, only responding on request.

Comment: 6 software Uarts impossible?

Comment: @iopertyki 
1 meter is a short distance, I have worked with I2C and I have not had problems.

Comment: @iopertyki: even only 2 software serials are "impossible", in general. `If using multiple software serial ports, only one can receive data at a time.` (see the reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to use RS485. RS485, instead of RS232 (The Serial you are using), is a protocol that enables several devices communicated on the same serial line.

For you to use this, you need to buy 6 RS485 IC, each one connecting directly to the regular serial port of the Arduino. RS485 works the same as RS232 Serial, but is an half-duplex channel where several devices can connect at the same time.

Comment: you have mentioned  **each one connecting directly to the regular serial port of the Arduino** then i need again 6 serial ports? can you show a diagram ? i don't get what the method is.

Comment: just one serial port. RS485 is basically a Serial Bus: Each devices connects one serial connection (TX + RX + 1 other GPIO) to a RS485 IC. all the RS485 ICs are conected on the same line. Whenever a device wants to write to the BUS, it turns the GPIO at HIGH then it communicates as usual. When the GPIO is at low, it is reading. This means that all the devices talk to all the devices at the same time.

Comment: I need one master Arduino to send data to other 6 Arduinos....diffrent data for each 6 slave arduinos.... reading data back to master from 6 Arduinos is not important here.

Comment: So it seems that RS485 fits your needs. One thing you can do is: The first character you send through Serial is the code of the arduino that should get the message. Every arduino will receive the message, but will only process it if the code matches to its own code.

Comment: do I need 7 modbus ICs?  1st i convert serial to modbus then again modbus to serial?

Comment: You don't need to use the Modbus protocol although you can if you want. You can do something simple: connect one IC to each of the arduinos and then connect all ICs on the same bus. That way, you can make every Arduino talk with each other by only using a serial connection.

Answer (score 0):

1 Meter is not a very large distance. I have been able to use the I2C communication over that distance, on a system of Atmega8 controllers, back when I didn't understand the beauty of Arduino. Had 3 of them connected to an Olimax Linux board, over a distance of 1 meter from the Linux board.

It should be no problem for the Arduino.